# How do I filter a text field, based on content type?

Tags: 7, input-formats

I've built a custom filter that parses images that were inserted into the node body field. I am trying to have the filter render image sizes based on the *content type* of the node being created/edited.

I cannot seem to find a way to get the *content type* of the node being create/edited. I assumed that it would be in one of the callbacks of [`hook_filter_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7), but it doesn't appear to be there.

Is there a way to filter a text field, based on the content type, or better yet - how do I communicate a setting from a *content type* to a filter?